# using a stream based on the content of Optional<Map>

Tags: java, java-stream

I get a map from a service not under my control that might be null and want to process it, let's say, filter, map and reduce to a single element I need.

Question: is there a "link" from Optional to Stream?

I tried (among other things):

```
 return Optional.ofNullable(getMap())
   .map(Map::entrySet) // gets the entryset
   .map(Stream::of)
   .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
   // i would then like to continue with
   .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith("f")
   .map(Entry::getValue)
   .findFirst();
```

but then I get not `Stream<Entry>` but `Stream<Set<Entry>>` ... is there a way to somehow flatMap a collection or map out of an Optional?

Note: I am interested in a fluent, pure stream/optional approach here. It works of course when I save the map to local var first and make sure it is not null.

Comment: cast Stream<Set> to Stream<Entry>? no, I can't.

Comment: You should probably consider changing your `getMap()` to return an empty map instead of `null`. You wouldn't have wrap it in an `Optional` then, and you would easily avoid such issues. As [Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks) says it, [Rule #4: It's generally a bad idea to create an `Optional` for the specific purpose of chaining methods from it to get a value.](https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14?t=27m55s).

Comment: In Java 9, [`Optional` will have a `stream()` method](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--), you could simply do: `Optional.ofNullable(getMap()).map(Map::entrySet).stream().flatMap(Set::stream)...`

Comment: yes, that looks promising ... however I'm in an enterprise environment and it took us a few years to adopt Java8 ... not sure I will be switching in July :-(

Comment: @Nathan : yes, that might be, I edited the question a couple of times and you were very fast. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @JanGalinski If you are in an enterprise environment and have already adopted java8, you should be thankful, I think... I wouldn't adopt Java9 until it is quite mature and frameworks and libraries are equally mature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
.map(Stream::of)
```

The `of` function takes a single parameter (or a vararg parameter), and returns a stream with only that element. You will therefore get a `Stream<Set<Map.Entry>>`. Instead, you should call the stream method on the entryset, like this:

```
.map(Set::stream)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm going to answer the question.

```
 return Optional.ofNullable(getMap())
   .map(Map::entrySet) // gets the entryset
   .map(Stream::of)
   .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
   // i would then like to continue with
   .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith("f")
   .map(Entry::getValue)
   .findFirst();
```

I'm sick, really sick when I saw above code. Is it really so important for you write code in fluent approach, instead of writing simple code? first of all, as @ Didier L mentioned in the comments, it's wrong way to use `Optional`. Secondly, the code is so hard to read, isn't it? if you write it with defining a local variable:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = getMap();

return map == null ? Optional.<Integer> empty() 
                   : map.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith("f")).map(Entry::getValue).findFirst();
```

Isn't it much clear? Or you can do it with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) if you can't get over not using fluent approach:

```
StreamEx.ofNullable(getMap())
        .flatMapToEntry(Function.identity())
        .filterKeys(k -> k.startsWith("f")).values().findFirst();
```

Or my library [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
EntryStream.of(getMap()).filterByKey(k -> k.startsWith("f")).values().first();
```

Always trying to look for a better approach if things are stuck.