# Flattening a list of elements in Java 8 Optional pipeline

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have a `id` value which can be `null`. Then I need to call some service with this `id` to get a list of trades and fetch the first not `null` trade from the list.

Currently I have this working code

```
Optional.ofNullable(id)
    .map(id -> service.findTrades(id))
    .flatMap(t -> t.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst())
    .orElse(... default value...);
```

Is it possible to implement a line with a `flatMap` call more elegantly? I don't want to put much logic in one pipeline step.

Initially I expected to implement the logic this way

```
Optional.ofNullable(id)
    .flatMap(id -> service.findTrades(id))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(... default value...);
```

But `Optional.flatMap` doesn't allow to flatten a list into a set of it's elements.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know if this is elegant or not, but here's a way to transform the optional in a stream before initiating the stream pipeline:

```
Trade trade = Optional.ofNullable(id)
    .map(service::findTrades)
    .map(Collection::stream)
    .orElse(Stream.empty()) // or orElseGet(Stream::empty)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(... default value...);
```

---

In Java 9, [`Optional` will have a `.stream()` method](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--), so you will be able to directly convert the optional into a stream:

```
Trade trade = Optional.ofNullable(id)
    .stream() // <-- Stream either empty or with the id
    .map(service::findTrades) // <-- Now we are at the stream pipeline
    .flatMap(Collection::stream) // We need to flatmap, so that we
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)    // stream the elements of the collection
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(... default value...);
```

Comment: plus one for mentioning the `stream` in `Optional` in jdk-9.

Comment: Thanks! But I think this line `.orElse(Stream.empty())` isn't needed as my `service` is actually Spring JPA repo and even result entries list is empty it is never `null`.

Comment: @Andriy You need the `.orElse(Stream.empty())` to get the object inside the `Optional` (in your case, the stream of trades), otherwise you would still have `Optional` in the pipeline. With that `.orElse(Stream.empty())` you can get rid of the `Optional` and start working with the stream.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way to do it by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx.ofNullable(id)
    .flatMap(id -> service.findTrades(id))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(... default value...);
```

I just saw: "[As Stuart Marks says it, Rule #4: It's generally a bad idea to create an Optional for the specific purpose of chaining methods from it to get a value..](https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14?t=27m55s)" in the comments under [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567806/using-a-stream-based-on-the-content-of-optionalmap):

Comment: Interesting video. Thanks!